# Boost Converter 9v to 450v as Capacitor Charger

Tags: mosfet, inductor, boost, mosfet-driver, coil

I recently decided to build a simple single-stage coilgun that is triggered by a SCR. For that, I had to design a low-power boost converter that only draws around 2 W at 9 V so I can power it from a 9 V battery. The booster works as expected and charges the cap in roughly a minute. The booster works in DCM (I believe) at a frequency of 7 kHz and a duty cycle of 75%, I mainly used [image: STP4NK60Z] MOSFETs for the converter.

However, when connected as shown below, the MOSFET of the converter always dies (short between drain and source) after the 450 V 1000 uF cap has discharged into the coil, or when the converter charges the capacitor again. I thought about some inrush currents due to the large current intake of the cap at the beginning of its charge, but the converter's alleged peak current (~0.6 A?) doesn't exceed any max. ratings, I also did soft start the cap and had the same problems. Then I thought about MOSFET protection and added a Zener diode between the gate and GND, as well as a snubber, which once again had no impact. I used pretty cheap MOSFETs with on-resistances of 2-4 Ω and max. current ratings of 2-4 A. However, I also tried to use an IRFP460 and it also died after only a few charges. I think that it could have something to do with the MOSFET missing a proper gate driver, some EMF issues, or the inductor going into saturation.
What do you think is causing the MOSFET to fail and what do I have to change to prevent the MOSFET from it?

Comment: Is D1 still operational after the MOSFET fails?

Comment: Correction: I mainly used STP4NK60Z mosfets for the converter*

Comment: D1 is still functional after the mosfet failed, as well as the other diode

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do to know when to stop the charging? What voltage do you charge the big capacitor to?

Comment: I switch the circuit off  manually at 350v, it charges rather slow so i dont need a cut off circuit

Comment: @kallgakr Please discuss what you imagine happens to the coil when the capacitor being discharged is finally finished discharging through it and the coil is at its peak current.

Comment: Using an isolated converter (such as a flyback converter) instead of a standard boost converter might help matters. It'll also make it easier to achieve your high boost ratio.

Comment: @periblepsis When the scr closes due to the falling current of the capacitor, there is a large reverse current building up in L2. The purpose of D2 is to give this current a different path so it doesnt  destroy the scr. However, only using a diode decreases the velocity cuz there is a larger time period where current is running trough it. I thought about adding a resistor in series with d2 to speed up the process and also tried out to use a 450v 10uf Capacitor in series. Im not exactly Sure how this capacitor behaves but with it, i had a velocity increase of like 50%, so i just kept it.

Comment: @Hearth Im aware that a flyback converter is probably the best Option for that but this circuit works really well for my purposes and is reliable when not used together with the discharge circuit shown below, so i assumed that there is an easy fix for it

Comment: Could it be that the reverse current of L2 does have something to do with the failure of Q1?

Comment: @kallgakr When the 450 V 1000 mF capacitor has no longer any voltage across it (close to it, anyway), the coil must start to have its peak current decline. At that very moment, the voltage across the coil reverses polarity. Then, as the right end of it is close to ground (through the SCR still) the other end goes negative with respect to ground. It must. At this point the cathodes of both D1 and D2 are forward biased (or may be.) Q1's body diode is also forward biased, as well. And you are still also allowing your 555 to run, as well. What do you see there at this moment and moments following?

Comment: _"works in DCM (I believe)"_ Believe is for church. In engineering you calculate, measure and find out. Have you simulated your circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the capacitor in series, you end up with a "standard" pulsing circuit, where D2 is keeps the current flowing through the coil, slowly dissipating the energy.

When you add the series capacitor, you close down this diode path after a slight initial surge, once the capacitor has charged enough.

What then happens, is that you force the freewheeling current instead to go through the SCR (it can cope well) and the Q1 body and D1:

[image]

The diode is rather beefy with a generous surge current rating, it looks capable of surviving a few pulses. But with Q1 being a tiny MOSFET, it is not ready for the 100s (?) of Amps.

If you want to achieve a shorter pulse, reduce the inductance and resistance of the coil. This will increase current, but as long as the switch losses remain small, you still transfer most of the energy into the magnetic field.

Comment: So the adding of the 450v 10 uf cap leads to practically the same result as having no reverse current at all? But why is the current able to go through the MOSFET in the blocking direction of D1? Is it because d1 temporarily breaks down? I also fear reducing the size of L2  since it already is rather small and it will worsen the velocity. ( I tried a smaller coil without the reverse cap with a much smaller inductance and had a velocity decrease of like 50%) Are there no other ways to give the reverse current a different, fast way to flow?

Comment: @kallgakr Nono, both D1 and Q1's diode are forward biased. See also the comment by periblepsis. The current flows rightwards in your schematic and the voltage between D1 and L2 will be negative two diode drops during this phase. I have added a sketch of the freewheeling current loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Do u think that replacing the 450v 10uf cap with some low ESR film or ceramic capacitors in parallel would help that this current way doesn't get blocked so fast( or is the capacitor in series with d2 just generally a stupid idea?).

Comment: @kallgakr I think it is a bad idea to put the series capacitor at all (as is). I think there are some strategies that use a second capacitor to catch the flyback charge, but these could probably use IGBT instead and implement more switching to exchange the first and second cap (for energy recovery).

Comment: What would happen if i put a resistor in series with d2 instead of a cap? One which has a resistance high enough that the magnetic field of the reverse current, even though it exists longer, is too weak to pull the projectile back to the center of the coil and thus decrease the velocity.

Comment: @kallgakr Even a tiny series impedance in the path of D2 will lead to very large current through Q1. Let's say you put only 10 mOhm (!!) in series. At 100 A, this will be already a 1V drop, enough to render the D2-path essentially insulating, so the majority of the current would go through Q1-D1 instead. That said, your current choice D2 will not work well either, you need a much beefier diode there, roughly equivalently beefy as the SCR.

Comment: I assume with beefier u mean a higher forward surge current, over 600A?

Comment: @kallgakr Yes, that's what I mean. These surge ratings are given for something like 10ms pulses usually, so you might be able to get away with less. But the beefier the better because it will also make the ESR of the diode lower.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm guess of @tobalt ... 600 A peak, ~ 1 ms pulse.
Made with microcap v12. https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110.

[image]

Here is the picture for v(vp) ...

[image]

Update with a diode accross M1.

[image]

And in fine ... Note that the current in L1 is higher ...

[image]

[image]

Added views with \$L2 = 85 uH \$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, ig something like 400A then still flows through the mosfet?

Comment: @tobalt I will add this voltage ...

Comment: @kallgakr perhaps more ... Depending of the "time step". I make a new simulation to confirm. I added also a diode (d3) accross M1 and "some" parasitics components.

Comment: Thank u very much for that simulation

Comment: My L2 Coil is significantly larger than 10uH, would it be possible to re-simulate the graphs in the third picture only with the inductance of L2 changed to 85uH? I would very much appreciate it. Also, is the simulation software that you are using LTSpice? @Antonio51

Comment: Added picture fo L2 = 85 uH. Made with microcap v12. https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110